# Update HCMWorker RecId field based on Personnelnumber

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have received an CSV file which provides me a SalesQuotationId and a Personnelnumber, I have created a Job to find the SalesQuotation via the `find` method.

On the SalesQuotationTable I have a field, stored with the `RecId` of the `HCMWorker`. The problem is, I only have the Personnel number in the CSV file. I can't find out how to change the RecId of the HCMWorker based on the PersonnelNumber.

```
static void UpdateHCMWorkerField(Args _args)
{
    #File
    CommaTextIo         inFile;
    Container           con;
    int                 i;
    FileIOPermission    permission;
    FilePath            readFile;

    SalesQuotationTable           salesQuotationTable;
    SalesQuotationId       quotationId;
    str                    worker;


    HcmWorker                     hcmWorker;
    ;
    readFile = "File.csv";

    permission = new FileIOPermission(readFile, #io_read);
    permission.assert();

    inFile = new CommaTextIo(readFile, #io_read);
    inFile.inFieldDelimiter(",");

    while (inFile.status() == IO_Status::Ok)
    {
        con = inFile.read();

        quotationId = conPeek(con,1);
        worker = conPeek(con,2);

        salesQuotationTable = salesQuotationTable::find(quotationId,true);

        if(salesQuotationTable && worker) {
            ttsBegin;


// Obviously, this is not working working because I am trying to update the RecId field with a string value.

      salesQuotationTable.WorkerField = worker;
        salesQuotationTable.update();

            ttscommit;
        }
        info("Done!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find *HcmWorker* record by *PersonnelNumber* using static function `findByPersonnelNumber` on *HcmWorker* table. Just replace `salesQuotationTable.WorkerField = worker;` with

```
salesQuotationTable.WorkerField = HcmWorker::findByPersonnelNumber(worker).RecId;
```